# On postback css setting deleted from masterpage

Tags: css, asp.net, master-pages

I saw several post similar to mine but couldn't find a solution that fits my issue (the masterpage issue :) ).
I have a masterpage with side menu , that I created with a list (ul > li).
Whenever I select a li which refers to nowhere("ftq" for example) - the function works great and changes the css setting as I want.
But, whenever I select a li which refer to a "real" page ("updateinspec.aspx" for example) and there's a postback, all the CSS is gone .

here's the code - any help will be great

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="MasterVC.master.vb" Inherits="HangarApp.MasterVC" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <link href="MasterCSS.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function myFunction(x) {
            x.classList.toggle("change");
        }


        var lst;
        function cngclass(obj) {
            if (lst) lst.className = '';
            obj.className = 'listactive';
            lst = obj;
        }

    </script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="headtitlePH" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div id="topcontent"> 
          <div class="menudiv" onclick="myFunction(this)">
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>

 </div>  
         <div class="divtitle">
         <img src="../images/logo1.png" /> 
                  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="userlbl" style="padding:12%;"></asp:Label>
         </div>    

    </div>
    <div id="subtopdiv">
       <div id="sub_inspec">
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="stationname" runat="server"  CssClass="subtopdiv"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="stationcode" runat="server"  Visible="false"  ></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="linecode" runat="server"  Visible="false"></asp:Label>
           <asp:Label ID="typecode" runat="server"  Visible="false"></asp:Label>
           <asp:Label ID="lblinspecnum" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
       </div>

    </div>

    <div id="maincontent">
           <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
          <h1></h1>
        <div class="innerdiv" id="divlefttop">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="divlefttopPH" runat="server">
             </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div class="innerdivdtop" id="divrighttop" runat="server">
              <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="divrighttopPH" runat="server">
             </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div class="innerdivld" id="divleftdown" runat="server">
              <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="divleftdownPH" runat="server" >
              </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div class="innerdivd" id="divrightdown">
              <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="divrightdownPH" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div id="leftcontent">

               <div id="menuinsp" runat="server">
                     <ul>
                      <li><a onclick="cngclass(this);" class="active" href="Inspec_Main.aspx">Inspection APP</a></li>
                      <li><a onclick="cngclass(this);" class="nactive" href="#ftqpage">FTQ</a></li>
                      <li><a onclick="cngclass(this);" class="nactive" href="#managepage">MANAGE</a></li>
                      <li><a onclick="cngclass(this);" class="nactive" href="UpdateInspec.aspx">UPDATE</a></li>
                       <li><a onclick="cngclass(this);" class="nactive" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                   </div>


    </div>
         <div id="footercontent">
            <label>LAHAV IT SYSTEM - DANA B COHEN  - TEL:58840</label> 
    </div>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="footertitlePH" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your master page isn't in the same directory as the `aspx` pages and you didn't use correct `href` in below `link`:

```
<link href="MasterCSS.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

You need use server side link like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079791/css-wont-apply-from-master-page).

Comment: my link is correct. Today I relieazed that if I double click the list items with redirect to a certain location, everything works fine and it looks "active" (as in for the list items that don't redirect - one click is enough to make it look active). What can cause that?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Mastercss.css link as given below and let us know if problem still exist.

> `<link href="/MasterCSS.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: Hi. my master page is in the right place. Today I relieazed that if I double click the list items with redirect to a certain location, everything works fine and it looks "active" (as in for the list items that don't redirect - one click is enough to make it look active). What can cause that?

Comment: Your aspx page shows that you are redirecting few links so these links will not be able to highlight after clicking. You need to modify these links class attribute as soon as page is ready to use. You can use following Jquery code with little modification. $(document).ready(function () {
$(".menuinsp ul li").each(function () { $(this).find("a").each(function () { var pageName = document.location.href.substring(document.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1, 100) if (this.getAttribute("href").toLocaleLowerCase().includes(pageName.toLocaleLowerCase())) {  $(this).attr("class",active");
} }) }) })